# Why is below program giving me error when I am assigning true or false to a vector of type bool?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I was doing a [problem](https://arena.topcoder.com/#/u/practiceCode/1240/1490/1593/1/1240) on TopCoder for finding the longest path in an acyclic directed graph. I have used vector of type bool for visiting vertices. But it is giving me these errors (highlighted in the code below):

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<bool>’ and ‘bool’) 
visited[cur_ver]=true;

error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<bool>’ and ‘bool’)
          if(visited[i]==false)
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Circuits{
    vector<int>adj[51];
    vector<int>cost[51];
    vector<int>T[51];
    vector<bool>visited[51];
    vector<int>dist[51];
   int glm=0;
public:
    void topological_sorting(int cur_ver,int n){
        visited[cur_ver]=true;                       //error 1
        for(int i=0;i<adj[cur_ver].size();i++){
            if(visited[i]==false)                    //error 2
                topological_sorting(i);
        }
        T.insert(T.begin(),cur_ver);
    }

    void Longest_Path(int s,int n){

        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
            dist[i]=NINF;
            dist[s]=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
           int u=T[i]
           if(dist[u]!=NINF)
               for(int j=0;j<adj[i].size();j++){
                   int v=adj[u][j];
                   if(dist[v]<dist[u]+cost[u][v])
                      dist[v]=dist[u]+cost[u][v];
               }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
            if(dist[i]>glm)
               glm=dist[i];
}

int howLong(vector<string>connects,vector<string>costs){
    for(int i=0;i<connects.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<connects[i].size();j++){
            adj[i].push_back(int(connects[i][j]));
            cost[i].push_back(int(costs[i][j]));
        }
    }
    int n=connects.size();
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        visited[i]=false;
    topological_sorting(0,n);
    int lm=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    Longest_Path(i,n);
    if(glm>lm)
        lm=glm;
        glm=0
    }
 return lm;   
}
};
```

Comment: In howLong method you are pushing elements into integers

Comment: Hint for future questions: Cut the example down to the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the questionable behaviour. It doesn't have to *do* anything meaningful. Makes it easier to answer your question -- and is a useful debugging technique that will quite often lead to you finding the problem yourself.

Comment: unrelated, but keep a close eye on the combination of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` The first includes the entire standard library which is way, way more than you want or need. The second library takes everything in the `std` namespace, almost everything in the standard library, and places it in the global namespace where it can get in the way of stuff you write. Together you have tens of thousands of identifiers you are not using getting in the way of the identifiers that you are, and this can lead to very strange error messages and logic problems.

Comment: I know that.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Additionally, `<bits/stdc++.h>` is non-standard, non-portable, and killing compile times. Show up with that at a code review (which a SO question effectively is), and you *will* get raised eyebrows. Better get rid of that habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing built-in array syntax and syntax of the `std::vector<T>` class. Precisely, with

```
std::vector<int> myVec[51]
```

you declare and *array of 51 vectors of type int*. Thus, the code

```
visited[cur_ver]=true;
```

means "take element 52 of the array `myVec`, and assign `true` to it". However, that element is not of type `bool`, but of type `std::vector<int>`. There is no operator that would allow to assign `bool` values to a vector object.

To specify the size of a vector, which is your intention, use the appropriate constructor or the `resize()` method. When you're sure that the size of your container is fixed and known at compilation time, you may use `std::array<size_t, T>`, which is a fixed-length array container, available in C++11. But this is not the case with your code - you insert elements later on.

Thus, to fix the error, fix the syntax for vector declarations, and then resize in your class' constructor:

```
vector<int> adj;
// other vectors follow ...
// in Circuit::Circuit:
Circuit:Circuit() {
    adj.resize(51); // others follow ...
}
```

Be sure to replace the `51` with a properly named constant. "Magic" constants are evil!

Comment: Got it. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are like dynamic arrays with an ability to resize. We've only two ways of the declaration of the vector in c++.

1. `vector <int> myVector;`
2. `vector <int> myVector2(4,1000);` 
   The second will initialize a vector of size 4 with initial value 1000. If you want to provide a size maybe you can use like this.

   ```
   vector <int> myVector(12);
   ```